# Javascript Send mail on Gmail with signature and BCC with Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

Is there a way with Javascript (or other) from Google Spreadsheet to get the Gmail account signature?

Details:
I have a Google spreadsheet with information in it.
When clicking on a button, it identifies who has to receive the information, prepare a mail, and send it to the person.
However, I want to add the sender's signature at the end of the mail (it includes name, phone, logo, etc.).
I'm open if I get the signature from an other place, as long as it can change according to who's sending the mail.
This is for my volunteering association, not a job.

In case my code may help (I look to fill the var Signature):

```
 var Signature;
 var Receivers;
 var Subject;
 var Location ;
    var MailtoSend= "Hello, \n\n The next meeting will be at " + Location + ".  \n" + Signature;
    MailApp.sendEmail(Receivers, Subject, MailtoSend);
```

---

#### SOLUTION:

I've find a way from another site (can't find it):
Create a template in your gmail draft with your signature, and put in the subject "Template" and in the body {Body}.
Then use the following code to create a copy of the mail, and fill it with all the information:

In the function to send the mail add:

```
sendGmailTemplate(RecipientTo, RecipientCC, RecipientBCC, SujetAEnvoyer, CourrielAEnvoyer);
```

Referring to the following functions:

```
function sendGmailTemplate(RecipientTo, RecipientCC, RecipientBCC, subject, body, options) { //mettre à jour la quantité de recipeien cc bcc to
  options = options || {};  // default is no options
  var drafts = GmailApp.getDraftMessages();
  var found = false;
  for (var i=0; i<drafts.length && !found; i++) {
    if (drafts[i].getSubject() == "Template") {
      found = true;
      var template = drafts[i];
    }
  }
  if (!found) throw new Error( "Impossible de trouver le brouillon 'Template' sur le gmail" );
  
  // Generate htmlBody from template, with provided text body
  var imgUpdates = updateInlineImages(template);
  options.htmlBody = imgUpdates.templateBody.replace('{BODY}', body);
  options.attachments = imgUpdates.attachments;
  options.inlineImages = imgUpdates.inlineImages;
  options.cc = RecipientCC;
  options.bcc = RecipientBCC;
  options.replyTo = "";
  
  return GmailApp.sendEmail(RecipientTo, subject, body, options); 
}


function updateInlineImages(template) {
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Get inline images and make sure they stay as inline images
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  var templateBody = template.getBody();
  var rawContent = template.getRawContent();
  var attachments = template.getAttachments();
  
  var regMessageId = new RegExp(template.getId(), "g");
  if (templateBody.match(regMessageId) != null) {
    var inlineImages = {};
    var nbrOfImg = templateBody.match(regMessageId).length;
    var imgVars = templateBody.match(/<img[^>]+>/g);
    var imgToReplace = [];
    if(imgVars != null){
      for (var i = 0; i < imgVars.length; i++) {
        if (imgVars[i].search(regMessageId) != -1) {
          var id = imgVars[i].match(/realattid=([^&]+)&/);
          if (id != null) {
            var temp = rawContent.split(id[1])[1];
            temp = temp.substr(temp.lastIndexOf('Content-Type'));
            var imgTitle = temp.match(/name="([^"]+)"/);
            if (imgTitle != null) imgToReplace.push([imgTitle[1], imgVars[i], id[1]]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < imgToReplace.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < attachments.length; j++) {
        if(attachments[j].getName() == imgToReplace[i][0]) {
          inlineImages[imgToReplace[i][2]] = attachments[j].copyBlob();
          attachments.splice(j, 1);
          var newImg = imgToReplace[i][1].replace(/src="[^\"]+\"/, "src=\"cid:" + imgToReplace[i][2] + "\"");
          templateBody = templateBody.replace(imgToReplace[i][1], newImg);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  var updatedTemplate = {
    templateBody: templateBody,
    attachments: attachments,
    inlineImages: inlineImages
  }
  return updatedTemplate;
}
```

Comment: If you provide yourself a solution, you may create a answer and accept it, so this thread can appear as answered.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a method to request a signature that you have already created. It is possible to create one yourself with inlineImages. The documentation for that can be found here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body-options

Comment: Hi Jordan, thank you for the information. I will have a look as a plan B if I can't bypass my need :)